# List of database users: can you run C# Code in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions

I'm trying to obtain a list of users associated with the AD Groups represented by the logons in my database. I understand from my research that the best way to do it is using this code:

```
{   
Server srv = new Server();   
//Iterate through each database and display.   

foreach ( Database db in srv.Databases) {   
   Console.WriteLine("========");   
   Console.WriteLine("Login Mappings for the database: " + db.Name);   
   Console.WriteLine(" ");   
   //Run the EnumLoginMappings method and return details of database user-login mappings to a DataTable object variable.   
   DataTable d;  
   d = db.EnumLoginMappings();   
   //Display the mapping information.   
   foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows) {   
      foreach (DataColumn c in r.Table.Columns) {   
         Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName + " = " + r[c]);   
      }   
      Console.WriteLine(" ");   
   }   
}   
}
```

is this the best approach? Also, this code is in C#, how will I be able to run it in my SSMS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only language<sup>1</sup> supported in SQL Server is T-SQL.  Having said that, it's pretty simple to use T-SQL to get the details you need.

```
/*
    Description: Display the Active Directory group 
    membership permission path for all users
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    [account name] varchar(255)
    , [type] varchar(255)
    , [privilege] varchar(255)
    , [mapped login name] varchar(255)
    , [permission path] varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC xp_logininfo;
DELETE 
FROM @t
WHERE type = 'group';
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY STATIC FOR
SELECT 'EXEC xp_logininfo @acctname = ''' + name + ''', @option = ''members'';'
FROM master.sys.server_principals
WHERE type = 'G';
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
SELECT *
FROM @t t
ORDER BY t.[account name];
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

The results returned show users with access to the SQL Server, and shows the group they are a member of that is providing that access.

You'll need [membership in the sysadmin fixed server role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions) or membership in the public fixed database role in the master database with EXECUTE permission granted to execute `xp_logininfo`.  You'll need standard user rights in Active Directory to enumerate the items in the directory.

---

<sup>1 - R is supported in [certain configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-r-services?view=sql-server-2017), and [Python is supported in SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and above.  Generally speaking, you'll want to use T-SQL.  Depending on your acceptable security posture, you may be able to use C# or Visual Basic to create a [SQLCLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) stored procedure that can be called from T-SQL in SQL Server 2005 and above.</sup>